# Spring Data Neo4j 4.2 query for labels or node id always return null

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Currently, I'm building a graph visualization app using Spring Boot & Neo4j. But when I call a method from my entity Neo4jRepository to get NodeEntity labels, it always returns a null value. Is the problem in my node entity?

This is my node entity

```
@NodeEntity(label="Personnel")
public class PersonnelNode {

    private Long id;
    
    @Labels
    private Set<String> labels;
    
    @GraphId
    private Long personnelId;
    
    private String personnelKey;    
    
    private String personnelNameIN;
    
    private Boolean isTeamLeader;
    
    private Boolean isQA;
    
    private Boolean isSuperUser;
    
    private Short companyGroupId;

    private Boolean isActive;

    private Timestamp created;

    private String createdBy;

    private Timestamp lastModified;

    private String lastModifiedBy; 

    @Relationship(type="PERSONNEL_TASK", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private TaskNode personnelTasks;
    
    private Long employeeDataId;

    public PersonnelNode() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<String> getLabels() {
        return labels;
    }

    public void setLabels(Set<String> labels) {
        this.labels = labels;
    }

    public Long getPersonnelId() {
        return personnelId;
    }

    public void setPersonnelId(Long personnelId) {
        this.personnelId = personnelId;
    }

    public String getPersonnelKey() {
        return personnelKey;
    }

    public void setPersonnelKey(String personnelKey) {
        this.personnelKey = personnelKey;
    }

    public String getPersonnelNameIN() {
        return personnelNameIN;
    }

    public void setPersonnelNameIN(String personnelNameIN) {
        this.personnelNameIN = personnelNameIN;
    }

    public Boolean getIsTeamLeader() {
        return isTeamLeader;
    }

    public void setIsTeamLeader(Boolean isTeamLeader) {
        this.isTeamLeader = isTeamLeader;
    }

    public Boolean getIsQA() {
        return isQA;
    }

    public void setIsQA(Boolean isQA) {
        this.isQA = isQA;
    }

    public Boolean getIsSuperUser() {
        return isSuperUser;
    }

    public void setIsSuperUser(Boolean isSuperUser) {
        this.isSuperUser = isSuperUser;
    }

    public Short getCompanyGroupId() {
        return companyGroupId;
    }

    public void setCompanyGroupId(Short companyGroupId) {
        this.companyGroupId = companyGroupId;
    }

    public Boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastModified() {
        return lastModified;
    }

    public void setLastModified(Timestamp lastModified) {
        this.lastModified = lastModified;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public Long getEmployeeDataId() {
        return employeeDataId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDataId(Long employeeDataId) {
        this.employeeDataId = employeeDataId;
    }

    public TaskNode getPersonnelTasks() {
        return personnelTasks;
    }

    public void setPersonnelTasks(TaskNode personnelTasks) {
        this.personnelTasks = personnelTasks;
    }

}
```

My Dao Class

```
@Component
public class PersonnelNodeDao implements IPersonnelNodeDao {

    private PersonnelNodeRepository personnelRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public PersonnelNodeDao(PersonnelNodeRepository personnelRepository) {
        this.personnelRepository = personnelRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public PersonnelNode getByEmployeeDataId(Long employeeDataId) {
        return personnelRepository.findByEmployeeDataId(employeeDataId);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonnelNode getByPersonnelId(Long personnelId) {
        return personnelRepository.findByPersonnelId(personnelId);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getLabelsByPersonnelId(Long personnelId) {
        return personnelRepository.getLabelsByPersonnelId(personnelId);
    }

}
```

And this is my Neo4jRepository Class

```
public interface PersonnelNodeRepository extends Neo4jRepository<PersonnelNode, Long> {

@Query(""
        +"MATCH (p:Personnel)-[r:PERSONNEL_EMPLOYEE]->(e:Employee) "
        + "WHERE e.employeeDataId = {0} RETURN p")
PersonnelNode findByEmployeeDataId(Long employeeDataId);

@Query("MATCH (p:Personnel) WHERE p.personnelId = {0} RETURN p, ID(p), labels(p)")
PersonnelNode findByPersonnelId(Long personnelId);

@Query(""
        + "MATCH p=(n:Personnel)-[r:PERSONNEL_TASK]->(t:Task {isActive: true}) "
        + "<-[pt:PROJECT_TASK]-(j:Project) "
        + "WHERE n.personnelId= {0} "
        + "RETURN nodes(p) as nodes, rels(p) as relationships")
List<Graph<PersonnelNode>> getPersonnelLoadTaskGraphByEmployeeDataId(Long employeeDataId);

@Query("MATCH (p:Personnel) WHERE p.personnelId = {0} RETURN labels(p)")
Object getLabelsByPersonnelId(Long personnelId);
```

}

This is my service that calls the method

```
Object nodePersonnel = personnelNodeDao.getLabelsByPersonnelId(Long.valueOf("2"));
```

The result is same when i set return variable with my node entity in my service also in my repository, its always return null value

```
PersonnelNode nodePersonnel = personnelNodeDao.getByPersonnelId(Long.valueOf("2"));
```

Actually my problem is, just for this entity. For antoher entity i could get the node id and the labels. This is the data return for personnel entity.
[Data Retrun From PersonnelRepository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRX1M.png)

FYI I'm using Spring Data Neo4j 4.2, spring boot 1.5.2 and ogm 2.1. Thank you before.

Comment: Does this query returns the result when you execute from DB directly?
You need to use @QueryResult annotation and create a class which will be the result you expect from the repo layer

Comment: Yes, it does Lucia, that's query returns the result when I execute from DB directly. 
But, I have tried, the same method in another node entity to get labels or id, I got the results that I expected, without annotating using @QueryResult annotation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I tried to change the object variable becoming Set<String> it's work's, I got the node labels. But when I expected to return the @NodeEntity, I could not get node id and node labels. But for other NodeEntity class, it works perfectly, I could get the lables and the node id.

Comment: Couldn't understand what  is your expectation. Yeah since you are returning only the labels which are strings Set<String> works. What do you mean by you expected to return the @NodeEntity?
See in your return statement you are returning only the labels of node.
RETURN labels(p)

Comment: Actually, my expectation is when i call PersonnelNode findByPersonnelId(Long personnelId) method, in my Neo4jRepository, I got the node id and the node labels along with the entity properties. But i don't know why it doesn't work just for this entity, but for other entities, i could get the node id and the labels.

Comment: In this query - findByPersonId() why are you returning ID(n) and labels(n) explicitly.
It will be returned by default when you return n right?